# Duplicity, duply - Volume was signed by key x, not y, Task 'RESTORE' failed with exit code '22'

Tags: backup, duplicity

I have an issue when trying to `restore` brand new test backup, just created with `duply full` option.

I get an error:

```
Volume was signed by key E1B0ABA5CC893257, not CC893257
11:10:50.210 Task 'RESTORE' failed with exit code '22'.
```

The backup was successfully restored anyway, but I would like to solve this issue.

I have no idea where this other key is taken from...

Please check the gist with full backup/restore log.

https://gist.github.com/okrutny/7fec89a14b91291a75ccdb25364bae99

Answer (score 9, accepted):

it's the same key, just by it's longer name. that is a known bug in duplicity and the workaround is to give the key id in the form shown by duplicity either temporarily

```
duply <profile> restore /tmp --sign-key E1B0ABA5CC893257
```

or in duply profile conf file.

..ede/duply.net